# Are all correlation functions in a CFT non-zero?

Tags: condensed-matter, conformal-field-theory, ising-model, lattice-model, scaling

I am particulary interested in the Ising CFT. Is it clear/true that for any field $\phi$ and a large enough number $r \in \mathbb R^+$, we have that $\langle \phi(x) \phi(y) \rangle \neq 0$ if $|x-y| > r$?

In case such fields exist, are they expected to also be realized in lattice models? Or are they figments of the continuum description?

Comment: I'm wondering what you mean by "any field". Typically for CFT (1+1D or 2D), the two-point correlation function for two primary fields are always polynomially decaying, with certain h. And for a minimal model (e.g. Ising CFT), the two-point correlation function of descendant fields also decays algebraically. (perhaps even from conformal bootstrap, even higher order correlation function decays algebraically) And the descendant states should cover the entire Hilbert space.

Comment: Actually I don't know whether CFT can be translated into a lattice version. For instance, Ising CFT can describe some phase transition of Ising universality class, which from the RG point of view, the microscopic details of the lattice theory should not matter anymore. Maybe one can say that the lattice model at the phase transition point is the lattice model that CFT can describe. I don't know if it is true or if you mean that.

Comment: Meanwhile, phenomenologically speaking, the lattice version of edges of Moore-Read fractional quantum Hall liquid should be a lattice model for Ising CFT. As far as I know, the naïve lattice version of FQHE does not have exactly the same physical properties as the continuous version.

Answer (score 1):

For CFTs we actually know the precise functional form of the 2-point functions
\begin{equation}
\left\langle \phi(x)\phi(y) \right\rangle = \frac{C_\phi}{|x-y|^{2\Delta_\phi}}
\end{equation}
where $\Delta_\phi$ is the scaling dimension of your field and $C_\phi>0$ for non-trivial fields. You can look up the formula in DiFrancesco's Conformal Field Theory Eq. (4.55). This means that, yes, it is true that $\left\langle \phi(x)\phi(y) \right\rangle \neq 0$ even for $r=0$.

As for the second part of your questions I don't know.